# PowerShell lambda function with array parameter takes only the first element

Tags: arrays, powershell, lambda

I've come across a strange behaviour in PowerShell. I wrote a lambda function that receives an array parameter and when I'm passing an array to it, in the scope of the lambda function, only the first element is processed. Why is this happening and what can I do to get the desired behaviour?
This is an example:

```
...> $x = { param([string[]] $y) Write-Host $y }
...> $x.Invoke(@("yes", "no"))
yes
```

Comment: `Invoke()` takes an array of arguments as its only parameter - pass it a nested array: `$x.Invoke(@(,@("yes", "no")))`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you, I should've read the Invoke documentation first. Have a nice day.